# Array c programming absolute value?

Tags: c

I have to write a code for a program that takes an array with n elements and then checks if there are two consecutive values of the array with equal absolute values.The results must be displayed as following:

```
|v[i]|=|v[i+1]|
|v[j]|=|v[j+1]|
```

So

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int i,j,n;
    {
        int v[100];
        printf ("Please write n:");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        for (i=0;i<n,i++)
            printf( "Write the element %d",i);
        scanf("%d", &v[i]);
    }
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        abs(v[i])=abs(V[i+1]);
    printf("Elements are %d',v[i]");
    for (j=0;j<n;j++)
        abs(v[j])=abs(v[j+1]);
    printf("Elements are %d',v[j]");
```

When I run this,it shows like a thousand errors, but I think that the mistakes are logical. Can you tell me where am I wrong?

Comment: That doesn't look like valid C code to me.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/abs

Comment: What language is this?.. It starts like C, but then it becomes something completely different!

Comment: C does not have an absolute value operator.

Comment: It is c language..oh my god I feel so embarassed..

Comment: Can you post the errors?

Comment: But in my book about C programming (Im teaching myself) there is this exact question..

Comment: You have to work a little bit on your syntax...

Comment: Seems like you should start with a method declaration.

Comment: Why do you do "Write the element %d" N times, but only one scanf?

Comment: You are missing `main`, did you realize that?

Comment: @Saint: I rolled back your changes since they subvert the question, though the changes are necessary to make the code work.

Comment: @Saint; @Jonathan is right.Leave it as it is.

Comment: @user2685334; Please give us your expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `|` as the absolute value function.

Use `abs()` instead.

So you should be doing something like `abs(v[i])` ...

```
if (abs(v[i]) == abs(v[i+1]))
```

and so on.

Here's what I came up with ...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{
    int v[100];
    int n = -1, i;

    while (n < 1 || n > 100)
      {
            printf ("Please enter n (between 1 and 100):");

            scanf("%d",&n);
      }

    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
      {
        printf( "Enter element %d", i );
        scanf("%d", &v[i]);
      }

    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
      {
        if (abs(v[i]) == abs(v[i+1]))
        {
          printf ( "|v[%d]| = |v[%d]|\n", i, i+1);
        }
      }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are several other issues with the code can you elaborate on them.

Comment: You'll need to `#include <stdlib.h>` to use `abs`

Comment: Shafik, yes I've updated my comment. You are write there were SO MANY things to comment about ;)

Comment: Please, `main` needs to return `int`.

Comment: I did run it ... It does seem to work for the test case I threw at it.

amrith@amrith-vbox:~/so$ ./ab
Please enter n (between 1 and 100):3
Enter element 04
Enter element 1-4
Enter element 22
|v[0]| = |v[1]|

Comment: @amrith I notice you are new @ SO, as initially your was unformatted [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Yes but this is not the code I am looking for ..I need two consecutive numbers which have equal absolute values...not two equal numbers..

Comment: why don't you list, say, 10 numbers in order and tell us what you'd like the output to say. What the program that I and others have provided you will tell you when two consecutive numbers have equal absolute values.

Answer (score 2):

Use `abs()` function for absolute values. Include `stdlib.h` header for this.
Some other corrections:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
     int i,n;
     int v[100];
     printf ("Please write n:");
     scanf("%d",&n);
     for (i=0;i<n;i++)
     {
            printf( "Write the element %d\n",i);
            scanf("%d", &v[i]);
     }
     for (i=0;i<n-1;i++)
     {
            if(abs(v[i])==abs(v[i+1]))
                printf("|v[%d]|=|v[%d]|\n",i,i+1);
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Include math.h? I'd have thought you should include stdlib.h. But that may be linux specific.

Comment: @amrith - you're correct.  I don't know where `haccks` got `math.h` from for this case.

Comment: `fabs()` et al are in `<math.h>`; `abs()`, `labs()` et al are in `<stdlib.h>`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler; True. Actually I was thinking about `fabs()`.

Comment: @Carl; That was mistake. I thought about `fabs()` (which I read in *C how to program 6th edition--pg. no. 143*).

Answer (score 0):

You need to us the **abs()** function.   You need to make sure you have **brackets** set up right.  You also need to be careful when looping through arrays (you may go **out of bounds**).

Here is something that can help:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i,j,n;
    int v[100];
    printf ("Please write n: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf( "Write the element %d \n",i);
        scanf("%d", &v[i]);
    }
    for (i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(abs(v[i-1])==abs(v[i]))
        {
            printf("Elements at positions %d and %j \n",i-1, i);            
            printf("Elements are %d and %d \n",v[i-1], v[i]);
        }  
    }
    for (j=1;j<n;j++)
    {
        if(abs(v[j-1])==abs(v[j]))
        {
            printf("Elements at positions %d and %j \n",j-1, j);
            printf("Elements are %d and %j \n",v[j-1], v[j]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The mistakes are logical!if you try to run this,it is wrong,you can only enter the values...

Comment: `main` returns int, please use an online compiler if you need it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916000/online-c-compiler-and-evaluator

Comment: If you put values in this,the result is
The elements are2The elements are2Thelements

Comment: I put in new line characters...go ahead try that

Answer (score 0):

you can't use the "|x|" for absolute value. just for `or` statement and bitwise.

in order to do absolute you need to write the code yourself or use `abs` function

on top of that you have a bunch of synex errors

- No main function
- `printf("Elements are %d',v[i]");` isn't right, u meant to do `printf("Elements are %d",v[i]);`

some suggestions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{
    int i,j,n;
    int v[100];
    printf("Please write n:");
    scanf("%d\n",&n);
    for (i=0;i<n,i++)
    {
       printf("Write the element %d",i);
       scanf("%d\n", &v[i]);
    }

    for (i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
     if(abs(v[i])==abs(V[i+1]))
        printf("Elements %d and %d are absolute equal", v[i], v[i+1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Still missing several `{` characters.

Comment: Code does not compile and needs better formatting, many online compiler available if you need one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916000/online-c-compiler-and-evaluator

Comment: And  that last if statement is pretty useless.

Comment: `ads()` vs `abs()`?  Also, please write C99 code: you need `int main()` or `int main(void)` — no implicit `int`.  (If you must write older code, you're obliged to include `return 0;` or equivalent at the end of `main()` — C89 does not provide for skipping the return value from `main()`.)  And `abs()` is declared in `<stdlib.h>`, not `<math.h>`.  And your loop scope for reading is screwed up still (as it was in the original).  Variable `j` is unused. You don't check that the array is not overflowed.